# Implement P&P Feature with SmartTarget

Tags: smarttarget, profiling

If I remember correctly, Profiling&Personalization (P&P) gives editors the ability to mark a visitor's interest in "things" based on what Component Presentations were seen.

After a threshold, the visitor would start seeing Component Presentations related to that interest, again as chosen by editors.

**How would you implement a similar scenario with SmartTarget (ST)?** Based on [Neil's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13949060/395495) and how ST works, I'm guessing it's something like:

- Developers set ADF claims for Pages and maybe Structure Groups
- Business users create ST Promotions against those triggers
- When a visitor's session meets the triggers, ST presents the personalized content from the promotions

Is it possible to set claims based on Component Presentations? Maybe based on their metadata?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed implement all of those things, by simply having some good triggers based on ADF claims. You should try very hard to make it generic, though, as one of the biggest benefits of SmartTarget over something like P&P is that the  *SmartTarget user* is in control and doesn't have to involve developers every time they want to do a new Promotion.

So in other words, make sure that the users don't have to get someone to write code every time they want to do something new. Otherwise, you are throwing away the best part of SmartTarget.

Comment: Ok, so in the functional design I'd ask for triggers on generic things like current Structure Groups (or path), Products seen, or maybe Product types. I predict someone will create a "framework" for useful triggers, if I don't beat them to it. :-)